# WorkSpace from an Eclipse Application

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I am creating a standalone eclipse application and I need to acquire my workspace from the application. I don't want an Eclipse plugin as it wont solve my purpose.

```
IWorkSpaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
```

But this is gives me an exception as the workspace is closed.
Either my current workspace or any new workspace which could be accessed using a standalone application would solve my purpose.

Comment: You can only access the workspace from a plugin - this can be in an Eclipse RCP. The RCP can be 'headless' (no GUI).

Answer (score 0):

I use the below dirty workaround for this issue. You will need to manually updated the configuration for your RCP standalone.

1. Open the ‘*config.ini*’ file located in the ‘*configuration*’ folder (under your project location).
2. Edit the last line in the config.ini file :
   `osgi.instance.area.default=<Workspace Loc>`
3. Replace the  in the line with the location of your workspace.
   e.g.: `osgi.instance.area.default=D:/WorkspaceFolder/WorkspaceNew`

Important: Forward Slash (/) should be used as separator when specifying the workspace.